# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused only in browser

Tags: laravel, homestead, laravel-5.3

I am on OS X Yosemite, running the latest homestead with Laravel 5.3.

I am able to run and reset migration in terminal from OS X. I can see the tables when I connect to the database with Sequel Pro using standard connection. I even see the tables when I SSH into the virtual box and run `mysql -uhomestead -psecret`.

The problem is, when I try to register a new user from the browser, I get the `PDOException in Connector.php line 119: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` error. It works when I run `php artisan serve` and fill in the form at `http://localhost:8000/register`.

I tried changing `DB_HOST` to `192.168.10.10` but that causes migrations to fail.

I might have created some chaos while trying to install mysql. I installed it using homebrew. Then i ran `mysql.server start` and at another point I ran `brew services start mysql` because I was not sure if it was working.

Homestead.yml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code/laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel
      type: "nfs"

sites:
    - map: votingapp.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel/votingapp/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

.env file:

```
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_KEY=base64:xxxxxxxx
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
    APP_URL=http://localhost

    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_PORT=33060
    DB_DATABASE=votingapp_development
    DB_USERNAME=homestead
    DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

web.php file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Comment: Homestead includes MySQL. If you are using Homestead why would you be installing MySQL with homebrew?

Comment: If you are using Homestead you do not need to install MySQL. If you are intent on using a MySQL instance that is not within Homestead you will have to sort out the proper routing to access that instance from within Homestead which is where the Laravel code is running.

Comment: @Qevo I installed MySQL before I decided to use homestead. How do I disable or uninstall all instances of MySQL, if necessary? How do I setup the proper routing to access the instance in homestead? How can I access this MySQL instance using Sequel Pro?

Comment: No need to uninstall anything just yet. You can simply choose to use the MySQL within Homestead for now. I'll make an answer now for formatting's sake.  ... Looks like you beat me to it. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had the wrong port number. In the `.env` file it should be 3306 while in Sequel Pro it should be 33060.

According to the [Connecting to databases](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead#connecting-to-databases) of the Laravel manual:

> You should only use these non-standard ports when connecting to the
>   databases from your host machine. You will use the default 3306 and
>   5432 ports in your Laravel database configuration file since Laravel
>   is running within the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mamp in 127.0.0.1 add :8889 or the port your config mamp.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7noL7.png)

127.0.0.1:8889 or localhost:8889